# How can I skip elements in a range-based for loop based on 'index'?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, skip, range-based-loop

Is there a way to access the iterator (I suppose there's no *loop index*?) in a C++11 range-based for loop?

Often we need to do something special with the first element of a container and iterate over the remaining elements. So I'm looking for something like the *`c++11_get_index_of`* statement in this pseudo-code:

```
for (auto& elem: container) 
{
  if (c++11_get_index_of(elem) == 0)
     continue;

  // do something with remaining elements
}
```

I'd really like to avoid going back to [old-style manual iterator handling](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html) code in that scenario.

Comment: Use the construct which provides the functionality you need. That is, use normal `for` loop (if that solves your problem easily). Don't force yourself doing complex things which need not to be complex.

Comment: use an STL algorithm with the preferred range. only fall back on a `for` loop if *none* of the algorithms fit.

Comment: @Nawaz Right, but how about using `if (elem == container.front()) continue;` as a workaround? Not overly complex, is it? And we can still use the concise syntax. Still better than 3 lines of manual iterator handling as in pre-C++11 IMHO..

Comment: @Jay: don't, unless you want to pray each time that the container doesn't contain equal(==) elements.

Comment: @Jay: The correct way to do this is with iterators, not with indices (they aren't generic) or C++ algorithms (I don't believe any of them fit here). See Daniel's answer.

Comment: @Jay Depending on the container and the condition for skipping, this could be unnecessarily expensive. It might also fail if there are duplicate elements in the container.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath True.. I was thinking about containers containing pointers (99% use case in our code base)

Comment: @Jay: Containers shouldn't contain raw pointers if they own them, because this isn't exception-safe and doesn't convey the semantics that the containers *own* the objects. Instead you should be using a pointer-container, like Boost's `ptr_vector`. Also if there's one thing you should learn with C++ is this: **don't be lazy**. I know iterators are painful, but they are the correct way to do this and will help you learn how to write robust generic code. Indices don't always make sense but iterators always do.

Comment: @all Good discussion, thanks for all input and discussing various aspects!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Often we need to do something special with the first element of a
>   container and iterate over the remaining elements.

I am surprised to see that nobody has proposed this solution so far:

```
  auto it = std::begin(container);

  // do your special stuff here with the first element

  ++it;

  for (auto end=std::end(container); it!=end; ++it) {

      // Note that there is no branch inside the loop!

      // iterate over the rest of the container
  }
```

**It has the big advantage that the branch is moved out of the loop.** It makes the loop much simpler and perhaps the compiler can also optimize it better.

If you insist on the range-based for loop, maybe the simplest way to do it is this (there are other, uglier ways):

```
std::size_t index = 0;

for (auto& elem : container) {

  // skip the first element
  if (index++ == 0) {
     continue;
  }

  // iterate over the rest of the container
}
```

However, I would seriously move the branch out of the loop if all you need is to skip the first element.

Comment: Definitely prefer the branching outside the loop

Comment: One drawback to this is increased verbosity when you're getting the container from a function that may return an empty list, because then you end up with essentially two checks on container size

Answer (score 6):

Boost provides a nice succinct way to do this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> xs{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (const auto &x : boost::make_iterator_range(xs.begin() + 1, xs.end())) {
  std::cout << x << " ";
}
// Prints: 2 3 4 5
```

You can find `make_iterator_range` in the `boost/range/iterator_range.hpp` header.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a simple for loop with iteratos:

```
for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++)
{
    if(it == container.begin())
    {
        //do stuff for first
    }
    else
    {
        //do default stuff
    }
}
```

It's not range based, but it's functional.
In case you may still want to use the range loop:

```
int counter = 0;
for(auto &data: container)
{
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        //do stuff for first
    }
    else
    {
        //do default stuff
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: [Those should be pre-increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215947/skipping-in-range-based-for-based-on-index#comment77339338_21216043)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get the iterator in a range-based `for` loop (without looking up the element in the container, of course). The iterator is defined by the standard as being named `__begin` but this is for exposition only. If you need the iterator, it is intended that you use the normal `for` loop. The reason range-based `for` loop exists is for those cases where you do not need to care about handling the iteration yourself.

With `auto` and `std::begin` and `std::end`, your `for` loop should still be very simple:

```
for (auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); it++)
```

Comment: Using post-increment here introduces pointless potential for overhead, especially for containers whose iterators are class types instead of pointers. I wish everyone could get out of the habit of defaulting to postinc/dec.

Comment: @underscore_d It's called C++ for a reason right :P Can't the compiler just notice that the value isn't being used though?

Comment: @GeeTransit Yes, but it doesn't have to, especially with complex iterators that might have side-effects it doesn't analyse as being no-ops. And yes, it being called C++ is a tad unfortunate, but I doubt "++C" would've had the same ring to it, so here we are. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When iterating over elements, always prefer to use an [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/), and use a plain `for` loop only if none of the algorithms fit.

Picking the right algorithm depends on what you want to do with the elements... which you haven't told us.

If you want to skip the first element, dump example:

```
if (!container.empty()) {
   for_each(++container.begin(), container.end(), [](int val) { cout << val; });
}
```

Comment: I get your point, though it's usually a bunch of things we do with our business objects so even lambdas could get biggish and out of hand. Still a problem with `for_each` when we need to skip handling for one of the elements, isn't it?

Comment: If the skipping is based on the index, you're probably doing something wrong. Restructure your data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of knowing how far an element is within the container without having an iterator, pointer or an intrusive index. Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
int index= 0;
for (auto& elem: container) 
{
  if (index++ == something)
     continue;

  // do something with remaining elements
}
```

If you want to skip the first element, another way is to use a std::deque and pop_front the first element. Then you can do your ranged for loop with the container as usual.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this on a random access container, my habit is to iterate over the indexes.

```
for( std::size_t i : indexes( container ) ) {
  if (i==0) continue;
  auto&& e = container[i];
  // code
}
```

the only tricky part is writing `indexes`, which returns a range of what boost calls `counting` iterators.  Creating a basic iterable range from iterators is easy: either use boost's range concept, or roll your own.

A basic range for an arbitrary iterator type is:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct Range {
  Iterator b; Iterator e;
  Range( Iterator b_, Iterator e_ ):b(b_), e(e_) {};
  Iterator begin() const { return b; }
  Iterator end() const { return e; }
};
```

which you can gussy up a bunch, but that is the core.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using iterators, because the idea of a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is to get rid of them. As of [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), to skip the first element in your `container`, I would take one of the following approaches. I also include, for the sake of completeness, how to handle the first element separately:

1. **Handling the first element outside the loop**

   You can use `container.front()` which exists for all [sequence containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) to access the first element. However, you must make sure that the container is not empty to avoid a segmentation fault. Then, to skip the first element (or more) in the loop, you can use the range adapter [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view) from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). All together it looks as follows:

   ```
   std::vector<int> container { 1, 2, 3 };

   if(!container.empty()) {
       // do something with first element
       std::cout << "First element: " << container.front() << std::endl;
   }

   for (auto& elem : container | std::views::drop(1)) {
       // do something with remaining elements
       std::cout << "Remaining element: " << elem << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   Instead of `container.front()` you can also use another range-based for loop together with the range adapter [`std::views::take(1)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view). The advantage of `take()` and `drop()` is that they work safely even if their arguments exceed the count of elements in your `container`.
2. **Handling the first element inside the loop**

   You can use an [init-statement in a range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to define a Boolean flag (or even a counter). This way, the flag is visible only within the scope of the loop. You can use the flag inside the loop as follows:

   ```
   std::vector<int> container { 1, 2, 3 };

   for(bool isFirst(true); auto& elem : container) {
       if(isFirst) {
           // do something with first element
           std::cout << "First element: " << elem << std::endl;
           isFirst = false;
           continue;
       }

       // do something with remaining elements
       std::cout << "Remaining element: " << elem << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Output for both approaches shown:

> First element: 1
> Remaining element: 2
> Remaining element: 3

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MWKAaMkSFv84xs0H)